# Hibernate mapping of map<entity1, List<entity2>>

Tags: hibernate, list, dictionary, orm, mapping

I have no idea how to map that?! Here my classes.. Is it even possible, without manually filling the Map?

```
public class Configuration {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ??
  private Map<Room, List<Label>> roomLabelMapping;
}

 public class Label {
   @Id
   private long labelId;
   ??
 }

 public class Room {
   @Id
   private String roomMail;
   @ManyToOne
   private Configuration configuration;
 }
```

Comment: i am not sure we can map with value as List, but you can easily map<Room,Label> meaning you will have 2 entries for same Room and 2 labels. You can convert this map to a @Transient Map<Room,List<Label> using guava easily

Comment: And  you can use also implement custom Hibernate UserType or UserCollectionType for your complex type.